# Custom swagger documentation/ Where is my swagger setup?

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, yarnpkg, swagger-editor

I have a jhipster based Spring project, which uses yarn/angular on the front end, and Spring on the back. I am with trying to figure out how to customize the swagger page. Currently it auto-populates new API's using swagger-ui, which is great, but I needed to add more custom info to those API's, hence my problem.

But I'm confused on what's running swagger. It looks like there's a node package called swagger-ui-dist and I also see a src/main/webapp folder with a swagger-ui folder, containing an index.html page.

I think what I pretty much want is to replace the current swagger-ui auto setup, with swagger that reads a file that I can create online using Swagger editor.

Apologies, for what I hope are simple questions. I'm brand new at swagger and npm/yarn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit more research, I found you could create your own OpenAPI doc, but an easier method in Spring is to annotate the endpoint methods with the @APIOperation annotation. There are other swagger specific annotations as well.

In the parameters, you can give value="", notes="" and a number of other customized values that will clarify what your API does in Swagger. Then swagger auto fills it in when bringing up your swagger page.

I hope that helps anyone with the same issue I had.